# Should I install acoustic insulation in ceiling in basement with switchback staircase and no door?

Tags: insulation, basement, sound-proofing, home-theater

I'm finishing my basement. Is it worth it to install basic insulation or sound barrier insulation like Rockwool since there won't be a door at the bottom of the staircase? Above the basement living room is the main floor living room with carpet.

[image: Basement]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: My opinion would be since the floor above has carpet, save the money and not put acoustic tile in the basement. However if you want an even more deadened sound, go ahead with it. Depends on your budget.